# Can pubnub be integrated with rails devise for authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pubnub

Hi I am wondering if it is possible to generate authentication from devise and log user in their chat session using devise gem?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate unique access key for user while he's registering / logging in your system. This key can be used as auth_key in [Pubnub Access Manager](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ruby/overview/security.html#_pubnub_access_manager) so you can grant proper rights for given user.